# Homework on Binomial Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have another homework, and I don't get this particular sub-question. I need to understand it. I don't know what I'm supposed to do.

For the sake of brevity, I won't post the entire problem.

> What is the probability that the number of successes, r, lies within
> one standard deviation of the mean?

Here are the given and the things I've derived so far.

> n = 6 (trials)
>
> p = 2/3 (success)
>
> q = 1/3 (failure)
>
> Pr[X <= 0] = 1/729
>
> Pr[X <= 1] = 13/729
>
> Pr[X <= 2] = 73/729
>
> Pr[X <= 3] = 233/729
>
> Pr[X <= 4] = 473/729
>
> Pr[X <= 5] = 665/729
>
> Pr[X <= 6] = 729/729 = 1

*PS: I'd rather have an answer in mostly ordinary language, rather than pure equations. I need an understanding of the question, not a solution.*

Comment: Do you know what the standard deviation and mean of a binomial distribution are?

Comment: Yes, I do. Although I haven't come across this kind of question on the probability that has something to do with standard deviation and mean. Either that or it's definitely phrased differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\sigma$ denote the standard deviation and $\mu$ the mean of the Binomial distribution. You are then asked to find the probability that the number of successes lies within the interval $[\mu-\sigma, \mu+\sigma]$. It could be a good idea for you to draw this: on the line from 0 to 6, make a mark where the mean $\mu$ is and then go $\sigma$ steps to the right and make a mark and $\sigma$ steps to the left of the mean and make mark. Then it hopefully will be quite apparent which values fall inside these marks.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: What is the mean number of successes $\mu$? What is the standard deviation $\sigma$? What integer numbers $x$ satisfy $\mu-\sigma\le x\le \mu+\sigma$ (that is, what integers $x$ are within one standard deviation of the mean)? Now simply add up the probabilities that $X=x$ for each such $x$.

Comment: Please double check what I understood from your answer. I need to find the mean of successes, _r_, which is _μ_ = _npq_. Then I need to find the standard deviation _σ_ = _sqrt(npq)_. Treat the standard deviation _σ_ as like a change/delta from the mean _μ_. Add all probabilities that satisfy the coverage. ??

Comment: @solitude The mean is not $npq$!

Comment: @hejseb I may be confusing the equation for the expected mean and the equation for variance. Can you help me out?

Comment: @solitude: The standard deviation is, indeed, $\sigma=\sqrt{npq}.$ However, the mean is $\mu=np$. So, you're looking for integers that lie between about $2.85$ and about $5.15$.

Answer (score 0):

You want to find (where $N$ is your random variable):

$$Prob[Mean - Std. Dev \leq N \leq Mean + Std. Dev]$$

So substitute the words with the formulas for the moments.

The reasoning behind the above formula is that "within" one standard deviation is interpreted as being plus or minus that amount from some reference point.  The reference point here is just the mean.